# How to use default parameters in a function without following the order at which parameters are declared in it

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, default-parameters

```
function Person(fname = 'First Name', lname = 'Last Name', age = 'Age') {
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
    this.age = age;
}

let person1 = new Person('husain', undefined, 1998);
console.log('person1: ', person1); 
// output: Person {fname: "husain", lname: "Last Name", age: 1998} (as I want)
```

In this example of a constructor of a function class, while creating an instance, I want to use default values of the parameters defined in the constructor, but without following the order at which the parameters are declared in it.

One way I have found out which is shown in the code (passing `undefined` to the arguments which we want to specify (so that it will use the default value) and after that continuing to pass other arguments normally).

Comment: Use object and destructure it.

Comment: That is the way to do it, yes. `undefined`.